# 72-hours Tokyo Metro Pass from Narita to Asakusa

Tags: trains, tickets, japan, tokyo

On [Tokyo Metro](http://www.tokyometro.jp/en/)'s website there is a [24, 48, and 72-hours ticket](http://www.tokyometro.jp/en/ticket/value/travel/index.html), which can be bought from certain stores in Tokyo, and from Narita and Haneda Airport.

My question is this: since tourists can buy the tickets from the aforementioned airports, can I take the metro from either airport to Asakusa Station? (Changing one or two isn't a problem)

I know that there's also NEX and Skyline, but I'd rather take the usual metro mostly for taking pictures.

Also, can I simply scan it, like with Pasmo and Suica, or do I need to show it every time?

Comment: The Metro is mainly a subway service, as such your photos will mostly be of walls and tunnels unless you are at the rare points where the trains come above ground. Also, Narita is in Chiba and is not serviced by any Tokyo Metro services.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder I speak of subways *transforming* into suburban trains in my answer, and the Asakusa Line is one such case - they often continue beyond Oshiage onto the Sky Access Line and to Narita airport

Comment: @Crazydre However as you also mention the Tokyo Metro passes are not valid (as although the trains go through to different company lines, they aren't counted as the same service passed their postered "end point").

Comment: I can't remember what I used **exactly** when I first went there; July 2015,  but I do remember seeing all kinds of things on my way to Tokyo, like hypermarkets, forests, hills, etc.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder This one "Subway 72hr + Keikyu Return Ticket       A:￥2200" seems like it takes you to/from the airport. Is it a good option? Although it's only for Haneda.

Comment: @WadeTyler Are you sure you were on the Metro? Apart from specific stations (Tozai Line; Nakano and Nishi-Kasai - Nishi Funabashi, Ginza Line; Shiyuba etc. almost the whole network is underground. Companies that line share however, like the Keisei lines are mainly above ground.

Comment: @WadeTyler That would be your best bet IMHO if going to/from Haneda

Comment: @WadeTyler From Haneda that would be your best bet, from Narita the Keisei Skyliner combination would be your best bet.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder I think so, what I took looked like a normal metro, and stopped at every station to Tokyo. This was from the Narita airport.

Comment: @WadeTyler Suburban and even some regional trains in Japan look extremely similar to metros. Still not a metro, as again metros don't reach the airports unless you count the "extended metro" as a metro, which it isn't

Comment: @Crazydre I honestly can't remember what it was, I was exhausted after a 21 hour flight, but to me it looked 100% like a normal metro, people in casual clothing, both young and old, got aboard without any luggage at all.

Comment: @WadeTyler I have a feeling we are getting a metropolitan train service and the Tokyo Metro Subway company used interchangeably here. The Tokyo Subway Company rail lines do not extend to either the Narita or Haneda Airports however other suburban lines do (Haneda:Keiykyu, Tokyo Monorail - Narita:Keisei, JR).

Comment: After carefully reading everything you guys have sent to me, I have decided that if I went to/from Haneda Airport, I should take the "Subway 72hr + Keikyu Return Ticket A:￥2200". I have but one last question, if I may, what tickets or passes do I need for the buses in Tokyo? Suica and Pasmo are out, because I had Pasmo, and I spent **a lot** of money everyday.

Comment: @WadeTyler Probably the Free Kippu 1-day ticket for 1590 Yen. Good for the Toei buses which make up the majority in central Tokyo, as well as metro and suburban trains in central Tokyo

Comment: @WadeTyler Do you know which busses you intend to patronize and if you want to include trains as well? If you want a combination then as CrazyDre says, the Tokyo One-Day Free Ticket is what you want (it is a physical ticket). If you only want buses then the Toei Bus One-Day Economy Pass / Toei Bus One-Day IC is what you want (can have either a physical ticket or the data loaded on a Pasmo Card. Cost is 500 yen for adults). If you want any other bus services then you will have to look at other options. See http://www.kotsu.metro.tokyo.jp/eng/services/bus_ticket.html

Comment: I don't really plan ahead much when visiting, I like being in the moment, so I don't know where I`ll be going, just that it will be in Tokyo.

Comment: @WadeTyler In that case it is up to you, since they do have day tickets for almost every service (and all together on the Tokyo Combined ticket) it really is up to your itinerary each day as to what you decide to get. The link I left in CrazyDre's answer lists almost all of the cross company passes available in Tokyo (it however doesn't include company specific discounts like daytime discounts, weekend discounts of bulk purchased ticket discounts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These passes do **not** cover the suburban trains to the airport.

It's confusing, but in Tokyo many metro services are *transformed* into suburban trains at the official termini and continue into the suburbs, but the passes only cover the section where the service is actually classified as a metro.

Narita and Haneda are both outside these sections, so you would need to buy a ticket for the non-metro section. If coming from Narita, that is Narita to Oshiage, and if coming from Haneda, that is Haneda to Sengakuji. Then board your train, get off at Asakusa normally, and show both the pass and Narita-Oshiage or Haneda-Sengakuji ticket to any station staff, so they can help you get out.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder When you go from Narita to Asakusa, the junction from Keisei to Tokyo Metro happens at Oshiage, hence a ticket from Narita to Oshiage must be purchased.

Comment: You can buy a through ticket from a ticket machine / ticket window or use an IC card from Narita. I have done it many times before without any problems. After all the train runs through to the Metro Line after all.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder This question is about using the Tokyo Metro Pass.

Comment: @fkraiem Apologies, after re-reading it a few more times I finally understood what was being communicated. Perhaps changing "get off at Asakusa" to "continue through to Asakusa" would make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

All your options for Narita are pretty well laid out here:
http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2027.html

NOTE that the JR Sobu line seems cheap, but don't travel on it during busy times with your luggage. There's no real provisions for luggage. You may want to consider mailing your luggage to your hotel as well. It's pretty cheap to do so in Japan and you'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, (the link does not have any mention on the Tokyo Metro 24, 36, 72 hour tickets that OP is asking about). Further, the posting of just links and not their content is usually discouraged due to links degrading. On another note, I have ridden the Sobu Line with luggage during rush hour before and although it isn't impossible to do, it certainly wont be a comfortable experience.